# Why is the limit $\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{2x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}-\arctan x=\pi/2-2$ and not $\pi/2 + 2$?

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

Why is the limit $$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{2x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}-\arctan x=\pi/2-2$$ and not $\pi/2 + 2$?

Evaluating I calculate the "2" to be positive but wolfram alpha says its negative. I've made the mistake before but can't figure out what the reason is.

Comment: **Hint :** $2x/\sqrt{1+x^2}$ tends to $-2$ and $\arctan(x)$ tends to $-\pi/2$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe: That's some hint! :-)

Comment: yes but how do I reach the conclusion that the first term tends to -2 algebraically?

Comment: Don't miss the $-$ in front of $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{2x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{-2t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}=\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{-2}{\sqrt{1+\frac 1{t^2}}}=-2$$

Quite possibly, the error might have occurred when you would have directly taken x inside the square root.

Comment: Oh I never used that method, are you supposed to do that whenever x approaches negative infinity?

Comment: The only thing you aren't supposed to do is
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{2x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\ne \lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{2}{\sqrt{1+\frac 1{x^2}}}$$

Comment: $\sqrt{1+x^2}\to |x|$ for when $x\to -\infty$, so ratio is like $\frac{2x}{|x|}\to -2$.

Comment: That's exactly what I did wrong @DatBoi thank you!

Comment: @edwindakwesi Glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

With *asymptotic equivalents*, it's still more obvious: we have $\:1+x^2\sim_{\pm\infty}x^2$, so $\:\sqrt{1+x^2}\sim_{\pm\infty}|x|$ and therefore
$$\frac{2x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\sim_{-\infty}\frac{2x}{|x|}=2\,\operatorname{sgn} x=-2.$$

Comment: thank you, that helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

$\lim _{x\to - \infty} \arctan(x) =-\frac{\pi}{2} $
and

$ \lim _{x\to - \infty} \frac{2x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \lim _{x\to - \infty} - \frac{2}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2} }}  = - 2$

Finally :

$\lim _{x\to - \infty} \frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2 +1}}-\arctan(x) =\frac{\pi}{2} - 2$

Do not forget that: $\lim _{x\to - \infty} \sqrt{x^2} = \lim _{x\to - \infty} - x$

Comment: Thank you, that helped!:)